# Generic Class type argument not clear?

Tags: c#, generics

I have just started Generics in dotnet. I was trying to learn about Generic classes and generic method when i got confused. Below I am pasting a code .

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Helper<int> helper = new Helper<int>();
        helper.helperMethod<string>("hello Ram !");
        Console.Read();
    }       
}

public class Helper<T>
{
    public void helperMethod<T>(T input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input);
    }
}
```

When creating an instance of the class,  type argument is used in the Helper class.

```
Helper<int> helper = new Helper<int>();
```

what is the purpose of using "int", or any other type argument in class if i can create a generic method itself. And also if type argument is used while creating a generic class why different data type is used in type argument as compared to generic method?

Comment: You wouldn't normally declare a separate generic type argument on `helperMethod`, as you've done here. And it makes it more confusing because you've then used the same *name* for the type argument on that method as you have for a class type argument.

Comment: There is no point in your example, because the type argument to the generic class is not used anywhere; therefore you can remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the purpose of using "int", or any other type argument in class if i can create a generic method itself

- To understand this, you certainly need to get deeper into the `generics`. Idea behind the `generic class or method` is simply to avoid any kind of `code bloating`. Since the same implementation can be used for multiple types, without making a separate implementation / overload for each type. Let's understand using some code examples:

> This code will work, because `T` has no relevance in the `HelperMethod`, `Console.WriteLine`, takes `object` base type as input, which is the base class for all the `T`

```
public class Helper<T>
{
   public void helperMethod<T>(T input)
   {            
      Console.WriteLine(input);
   }
}
```

> Let's look at the modifications possible:
>
> 1. Make just either a `method` or `class` generic in this case, since making both generic, adds little value, something like:

```
public class Helper<T>
{
   public void HelperMethod(T input)
   {            
      Console.WriteLine(input);
   }
}
```

> Or

```
public class Helper
{
   public void HelperMethod<T>(T input)
   {            
      Console.WriteLine(input);
   }
}
```

> 2. Even more important point, that makes generics worthy, is to introduce `Constraints`, because that's the only way to make them useful in real sense

```
public class Helper<T> where T:ICustom
{
   public void HelperMethod(T input)
   {            
      A a = input.Method1();
      B b = input.Method2();
   }
}

interface ICustom
{
   A Method1();

   B Method2();     
}

Class A
{
  // Fields and Properties of Class A
}   

Class B
{
  // Fields and Properties of Class B
}
```

Importance of doing so is, the generic type can be used to call the relevant methods and use the output in the generic method, like `A and B` types in above case can lead to truly `Generic implementation`.

Another area where constraints are extremely useful is something like `Func<T,A>`, which can be supplied for the user to implement, something like:

```
public class Helper<T>
{
   public void HelperMethod(Func<T,A> input,Func<T,B> input1,T t1)
   {            
      A a = input(t1);
      B b = input1(t1);
   }
}
```

Here the `Func` implementation would be done by caller, but would ensure results as `Type A and B`

Answer (score 6):

There are two useful variants of the `Helper` class, that would be clearer, depending on the intended effect:

1. Having a type argument only on the class

   ```
   public class Helper<T>
   {
       public void helperMethod(T input)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(input);
       }
   }
   ```

   In this case, the `Main` method as written will result in compilation error, because `Helper<int>.helperMethod` only accepts `int` for `input`.
2. Having a type argument only on the method

   ```
   public class Helper
   {
       public void helperMethod<T>(T input)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(input);
       }
   }
   ```

   In this case, `Helper.helperMethod` can accept any type.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the purpose of using "int", or any other type argument in class if i can create a generic method itself

No Purpose. You can just as easily create a static method that takes a generic parameter:

```
class Program
{

    static void helperMethod<T>(T input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input);
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        helperMethod<string>("hello Ram !");
        helperMethod<int>(1024);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

An extra point on this: the C# compiler is usually smart enough to figure out the parameter type for function calls such as those above, so you could just write:

```
    helperMethod("hello Ram !");
    helperMethod(1024);
```

> And also if type argument is used while creating a generic class why different data type is used in type argument as compared to generic method?

The example you post is too simple for there to be any benefit in doing that. You could have a generic class based on one type, and it could have a generic method call in it that takes another type. That method call would be part of a class that operates on type T, and the method itself takes a parameter of type Y. A simple example of this could be a Converter class that converts different types to the type of the class. i.e.:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var converter = new Converter<string>();
        var converted_objected = converter.ConvertThis<int>(200);
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class Converter<T>
{
    public T ConvertThis<O>(O to_convert)
    {
        T result = default(T);

        // do stuff with to_convert and the answer ends up in result

        return result;
    }
}
```

An overly simple expample, and it wouldn't work for all types, but I hope it helps you get the picture.

Regards,

Adam.